# Sphinx purge deleted data

Tags: sphinx, sphinxql

What is the best way to purge all old data from the Sphinx indexes? Right now, I issue an `OPTIMIZE INDEX` command, however this is only adding the job to the queue. Therefore, I thought if I measure the index size before the optimize command, I could wait in a while loop until the index is reduced in size?

Though, this doesn't seem to be the best solution. I have also tried `FLUSH RAMCHUNK` however this is affecting the RAM-chunks which isn't the solution I'm looking for. I want to purge not only the RAM-saved indexes, but the entire index.

What is best practice in this case?

Comment: what's wrong with using OPTIMIZE?

Comment: Like I said, it only adds the job to the queue. How do I find out whether it’s done or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Manticore Search you can use OPTION sync=1 for OPTIMIZE to make it wait until the job is actually done. The documentation is https://docs.manticoresearch.com/latest/html/sphinxql_reference/optimize_index_syntax.html